# AWS IoT Device sdk python user_data_set()

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot

In the `paho.mqtt` library it is possible to set the user data that will be passed to callbacks either in the constructor:

```
client = Client(client_id="", clean_session=True, userdata=myData, protocol=MQTTv311)
```

or at a later point with:

```
client.user_data_set(myData)
```

In `aws-iot-device-sdk-python` I would like to have the same possibilities to have access to `myData` when subscriping to a topic with:

```
client_AWS.subscribe("myTopic", 1, customCallback)
```

In the documentation ([aws-iot-device-sdk-python](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python/blob/master/AWSIoTPythonSDK/MQTTLib.py)) it says:
**Custom Callback:**

```
Function to be called when a new message for the subscribed topic comes in. Should be in form `customCallback(client, userdata, message)`
```

How can I manually set the userdata?